# How to connect MS Excel to Azure Cosmos DB-SQLAPI?

Tags: excel, azure-cosmosdb, excel-2013, powerquery, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to create an Excel table who can query the Database and interpret the data into styled tables so the users can understand it.

It's supposed to be able to query the whole server and put the outputs into precise columns, even if they come from different tables or databases.

I'm not the owner of the service, only a user, I found out I can access it from Portal.Azure.com and Cosmos.azure.com using the connection string it asks. It's a document database using the SQL API.

I've tried using Power Query complement of Excel 2013 with the "Azure SQL Database" option, the Web option and Data>Other Sources>SQL Server and nothing seems to be working.

It just stays at "invalid credentials", "invalid connection" or "error to connect"

How can I connect to the Database with the information I already have?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add the connection string when you install the ODBC driver and then pick it from  **`Data -> From Other Sources -> From Microsoft Query.`**

You can read about the **[Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/odbc-driver)** and how to setup connection from [here](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cosmosdb-odbc-excel-query.rst)